# Is there any tool to monitor the incoming requests to Redshift database?

Tags: redis, frontend, amazon-redshift, predis

I've implemented predis server. I can't determine whether my application is pinging the database every time or if it is taking data from predis. Is there any way I can check incoming requests to the Redshift instance? Or test the predis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure if I understood the question but if you are looking to see the most recent queries run on your cluster you can check the stv_recents view. Or if you have access to the AWS console, you can open the "queries" tab for your cluster for real-time query execution details.